# fpdf change date from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: php, sql, date, date-format, fpdf

In my phpmyadmin database year is saved as YYYY-MM-DD. But When I generate the pdf I want to change it to DD-MM-YYYY.

[image]

Code:

```
$pdf->Table("SELECT measurements.title as Maling, routines.value as Verdi, routines.date as Dato, routines.time as Tid, pools.name as Basseng, emps.user_name as Ansatt
FROM routines, measure_routine, measurements, pools, emps
WHERE routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
AND measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
AND (measurements.title  Like 'T_%') AND measure_routine.pool_id=pools.id AND routines.emp_id=emps.id AND Date between '".$fraDato."' and '".$tilDato."'
ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time;");


$prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
            'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
            'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
            'padding'=>2);




$pdf->Output($downloadfilename."$strf.pdf"); 
header('Location: '.$downloadfilename."$strf.pdf");
}
```

Comment: are you formatting the date in sql? i can't see it in your code

Comment: which RDMS are you using?

Comment: What have you *tried*? What worked? What didn't? Why is `DATE_FORMAT(routines.date,'%d-%m-%Y')` not a good tool for this task? See documentation:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way will be to format date directly in sql so change:
`routines.date as Dato` to:

`DATE_FORMAT(routines.date, '%d-%m-%Y') as Dato`

Answer (score 3):

```
$pdf->Table("SELECT measurements.title as Maling, routines.value as Verdi, 
         date_format(routines.date as Dato, \"%d-%m-%Y\"), ...
```